# parallel_tests - permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using a gem called parallel_tests (https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) to speed up my testing process.

However when I follow the instructions and run

```
rake parallel:create
```

I get an error saying that `/home/recar/code/myproj/bin/parallel_test` is not found.

When I do `mkdir bin/parallel_test` inside my project and run `rake parallel:create` again it it says `sh: /home/recar/code/myproj/bin/parallel_test: permission denied`

When I do `chmod 777 bin -R`  I see that `bin/parallel_test` has full permissions but when I run the rake command again I still get the permission error.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You've created `bin/parallel_test` as a directory, but `parallel_test` is actually the script that runs when you execute the rake task.

Can you give a full output from the rake task, by adding the `--trace` flag?

Comment: Yeah, seems that way. I'd try reinstalling it. Are you using bundler?

Comment: Yes, bundler.  I uninstalled parallel_tests and ran bundle install again

Comment: Did that help? If not, my best advice would be to go through the `parallel:create` task line by line to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: That was definitely the issue.  I just copied the binary from the system folder into myproj/bin

Comment: create doesn't actually do anything but that's a different issue I suspect